# Agile Web Development with Rails Chapter 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following the example write in Chapter 14 "Logging In" of the book.
I have my view in "127.0.0.1:3000/login" working well, but if i insert my user and password it returns this error:

NoMethodError in SessionsController#create

undefined method `authenticate' for #< User:0x9f75978>

How to solve it?

create method sessions_controller.rb is:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to admin_url
    else
      redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the `create` method in `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`?

Comment: @user1312490, double check if your `User` model has an `authenticate` method

Comment: in user model i found this implemented User.authenticate(name, password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trying to call `authenticate` on User, this means you probably don't have an authenticate method on user.  If you do, make sure it's not private.

Comment: @user1312490, and make sure it's not class method. Just `def authenticate`

Answer (score 2):

The code you give tries to call the `authenticate` method on an *instance* of a User object.

Based on you comment re: `User.authenticate(name, password)` you have an authenticate method only on the User *class* - and it takes both name and password as parameters.

To call the User class method, you'd instead use the following:

```
user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
if user && User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
```

Alternatively, look for an instance-level method called `authenticate` which (as @caulfield mentioned above) would look something like:

```
def authenticate(password)
  # does stuff
end
```

instead of `User.authenticate(name,password)`